# ejabberd keeps trying and failing to connect to proxy.eu.jabber.org

Tags: ejabberd

I'm running ejabberd 17.04, and it keeps trying and failing roughly every three minutes to open an s2s connection to proxy.eu.jabber.org.  The attempt fails because not only does proxy.eu.jabber.org not exist, but eu.jabber.org apparently doesn't exist either.

I know this connection is for federation, and I'd like it to work.  But I know neither where to configure what it tries to connect to, nor what server I should use in place of the nonexistent proxy.eu.jabber.org.  The proxy.eu.jabber.org address does not appear anywhere in its configuration files, not even as a commented-out default.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2):

> The proxy.eu.jabber.org address does not appear anywhere in its configuration files, not even as a commented-out default.

That address comes from old Pidgin clients, see [this ticket](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/17187): *Please, remove "proxy.eu.jabber.org" from default pidgin configuration*

> it keeps trying and failing roughly every three minutes to open an s2s connection to proxy.eu.jabber.org.

You can prevent those connection attempts in the server adding options like that:

```
s2s_access: s2s

access_rules:
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## If you enable this you also have to uncomment "s2s_access: s2s"
  s2s:
    - deny:
       - server: "proxy.eu.jabber.org"
    - allow
```

Comment: Pidgin doesn't appear to have anything in its configuration for my own accounts, either.  It's possible remote users' configurations have it.  I've just implemented the s2s deny; that should resolve the proxy.eu issue.

Comment: 6 years later and I also see quite a lot outbound s2s attempts to proxy.eu.jabber.org. Any new insight on that. Could that be one of my user's clients?